# Silverlight Website on Mobile Phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a Silverlight website and one of the functionality requirements is for the rotating images to show on all browsers. The test site looks great in all desktop computer browsers. The problem now is on mobile phones the system isn't loading. I can understand no plugin for iPhone, Blackberry, etc. but my problem is that on Microsoft's Windows Phone. On the Samsung Focus it asks to install, click install and I get Silverlight isn't available for the phone. Does anyone have an idea how I can get around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current browser for Windows Phone 7 does not currently support a browser plugin model.  As a result, Silverlight will not run in Windows Phone 7 browsers.

A future release of WP7 codenamed "Mango" is rumored to offer Silverlight in the browser. Unfortunately, you'll have to wait until then.

Your only option right now for mobile browsers that can't run Silverlight is to offer a mobile-optimized version of the site.  For the time being, there is simply no other option.

Answer (score 2):

IE for WP7 does not currently support Silverlight in the browser, despite it being used for native apps. There have been rumors that this will change in future releases but no official word from Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just make an app for the phone of your website. Like it was mentioned, silverlight is not supported in the browser for wp7 yet. But if you created certain functionality, classes, animations, etc. I imagine it would be quite easy to port this over to wp7.